# Greater than function in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I know this is an age old question and you probably have come across this aswell, but there's a bug in my solution and I don't know how to solve it. I need to write a function that compares two integers. I am only allowed to use the operations (!,~,&,^,|,+,>>,<<) and also no control structures(if,else loops etc).

```
isGreater(int x, int y) {
    //returns 1 if x > y.
      return ((y+(~x+1))>>31)&1;
}
```

my idea is simple, we compute y-x, we shift by 31 to get the sign bit, if it's negative, then we return zero else we return 1. This fails when x is negative and falsly returns 1 although it should return zero. I'm stuck at this and don't know how to proceed.

We assume that integer is 32bits and uses two's complement representation. This question is NOT about portability.
Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that you know the size of `int` leads to nonportable code.

Comment: @JohnColeman trying to get `x > y` with bitwise operations. I think it's safe to asume portability is not an issue

Comment: Code is assuming an `int` is 32 bits and uses 2's complement encoding.  These limits the portability of this task's code.  Best to learn portability than such tricks.

Comment: We assume 32bit and twos complement. We're not worrying about portability right now, since that's not the question.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/g/H1o9Xn

Comment: right-shifting negative number is also non-portable

Comment: @bolov this is a C question

Comment: @M.M correct, it can be `sar` or `shr`. But then you do `& 1` and the result is the same

Comment: @DariusTheGreat Explicit consideration of "assume 32bit and twos complement." are best in the post vs. only a comment and brings clarity to it.  It is reasonable to assume a learner who does not know this post's answer is also unfamiliar with the wide latitude of C's `int` width, padding and encoding potentials.

Comment: @bolov or anything else (it's implementation-defined with no restriction to the two cases you mention)

Comment: Using `int32_t` instead of `int` would be portable though.

Comment: @MarkWeston That still has the problems that right-shift is implementation-defined, and some systems may not even define `int32_t`. Really this question has to be accompanied by a bunch of  implementation-specific conditions

Comment: @bolov With the rarely used 1's complement, right shift and then `& 1` is not the same result for negative values.

Comment: guys. Portability is not an issue for this exercise. It's not like this code would be ever near a production code. It's just an exercise for bitwise operations. I agree that resources could be better spent learning something else than this useless tricks, but that is the exercise and the problem the OP has posted. I even agree that portability should be taught. But let's focus on the question at hand.

Comment: @M.M You're right about the right-shift. My bad.

Comment: Also, `~x+1` is undefined behavior if `x==0`, right? In any case, if OP doesn't use `int32_t` it's nigh impossible for us to debug. For all we know, OP might have compiled this on a platform that doesn't fulfill these requirements.

Comment: As to how to spot the problem, break the operation into fundamental operations and store each result in an intermediate value. Then, debug step by step.

Comment: @patatahooligan The tilde is said to flip every bit of the number's representation, so `~0` is all-bits-set integer, isn't it? And in U2 that is `-1` representation, which gives `0` when incremented. At least at architectures I have met, which is not a large number...

Comment: I think the algorithm runs into overflow problems if x and y are big enough values of opposite signs.  For example, if `x = INT_MIN/2-10` and `y = INT_MAX/2+20`, then likely result of the subtraction (assuming wrapping on overflow, which isn't guaranteed) is a positive number, which isn't going to give the correct result.  There are analogous problems with wrapping around the positive limit.

Comment: @CiaPan yes I think you're right. I thought that setting all bits to 1 and then adding 1 would be UB because of overflow, but it's not an overflow when the type is signed.

Answer (score 4):

Hacker's Delight has a chapter Comparison Predicates, which is exactly what we need here.

One of the things it writes is:

```
x < y: (x - y) ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) ^ x))
```

Which we can use almost directly, except that `x` and `y` should be swapped,  the subtractions must be replaced by something legal, and the result appears in the top bit instead of the lowest bit. Fortunately `a - b == ~(~a + b)` so that's not too hard. First applying those transformations:

```
// swap x <-> y
(y - x) ^ ((y ^ x) & ((y - x) ^ y))
// rewrite subtraction
~(~y + x) ^ ((y ^ x) & (~(~y + x) ^ y))
// get answer in lsb
((~(~y + x) ^ ((y ^ x) & (~(~y + x) ^ y))) >> 31) & 1
```

I have a website [here](http://haroldbot.nl/?q=%28x+%3Es+y%29+%26+1+%3D%3D+%28%28~%28~y+%2B+x%29+%5E+%28%28y+%5E+x%29+%26+%28~%28~y+%2B+x%29+%5E+y%29%29%29+%3E%3Es+31%29+%26+1) that says it works.

If local variables are allowed it can be simplified a bit by factoring out the subexpression
`~(~y + x)`:

```
int diff = ~(~y + x);
return ((diff ^ ((y ^ x) & (diff ^ y))) >> 31) & 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all let's clarify that we assume:

- negative integers are represented in 2's complement
- `int` is exactly 32 bits wide and `long long` is exactly 64 bits wide
- right shifting a negative number is an arithmetic shift

There is a problem with the `(~x+1)` part in your solution which is supposed to return `-x`. The problem is that the absolute value of `INT_MIN` is greater than the absolute value of `INT_MAX`, thus when x is `INT_MIN` then `(~x+1)` yields `INT_MIN` instead of `-INT_MIN` as you expected.

There's also a problem with overflows in the `y+(-x)` part of your solution (second step).

Now if you're allowed to use other types than `int`, we can solve both of these problems by casting the values to `long long` before the conversion, assuming that it's a 64-bit type, so that `(~x+1)` would return the expected result `-x` and `y+(-x)` would not cause any overflows. Then, obviously, we will have to change the `>>31` bit to `>>63`.

The end solution is as follows:

```
static bool isGreater(int x, int y)  {
    long long llx = x;
    long long lly = y;
    long long result = ((lly+(~llx+1))>>63)&1;
    return result;
}
```

It's feasible to test it with some corner-cases, such as  `x == INT_MIN`, `x == 0` and `x == INT_MAX`:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = INT_MIN;
    for (long long y = INT_MIN; y <= INT_MAX; ++y) {
        assert(isGreater(x, y) == (x > y));
    }
    x = INT_MAX;
    for (long long y = INT_MIN; y <= INT_MAX; ++y) {
        assert(isGreater(x, y) == (x > y));
    }
    x = 0;
    for (long long y = INT_MIN; y <= INT_MAX; ++y) {
        assert(isGreater(x, y) == (x > y));
    }
}
```

This was successful on my particular machine with my particular compiler. The testing took 163 seconds.

But again, this depends on being able to use other types than `int` (but then again with more work you could emulate `long long` with `int`).

This whole thing could be more portable if you used `int32_t` and `int64_t` instead of `int` and `long long`, accordingly. However, it still would not be portable:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators
>
> 5 The result of E1 >> E2is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.