# Make a function to return 1 if x <= y, using only bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

this is homework and I'm struggling with it along with at least the half of my class that I can see is here. Anyways. I need to make a function that `returns 1 if x <= y else return 0`.

We can only use: `! ~ & ^ | + << >>` and the max ops count is: `24`
All integers must be `signed` and there cannot be any calls made to any other functions that I've created or that C offers. We are allowed to assume all integers are `32 bits` and they must be signed.

I'm unsure of where to begin with this function. so far I have the following:

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
    int diff = (y+~x+1); //The same as y-x
    int diffSign = (diff>>31) & 1; //if negative, this will be 1. Else it'll be 0.
    return !diffSign;
}
```

This seems like it would work. But It doesn't work for certain inputs (according to the program that does the grading).

Here is a function that does work that I found online but I do not want to copy it. I would like to understand it and see why it works and mine does not. It seems that my code does not work when it overflows, and that needs to be handled.

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
  int sign, isLess, dif, equal, isLessorEqual;

  sign = x ^ y;
  isLess = ~sign;
  dif = y + (~x + 1);


  equal = !dif;

  sign = sign & x;

  dif = ~dif;

   isLess = isLess & dif;
   isLess = isLess | sign;
   isLess = isLess & (1 << 31);

   isLessorEqual = (!!isLess) | (equal);

   return isLessorEqual;  
}
```

If someone could help me **understand** the differences or how these functions work and handle overflow, that would be greatly appreciated and is what I am asking for. I'm close, just can't figure out this overflow thing

Comment: You're required to use `int`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes. Must be signed int. Cannot make a call to any other functions in C or that i've created.

Comment: Then this is *very misguided* because of the many undefined and implementation-defined behaviours. Least of which is that you assume the width of an `int` in `diff >> 31`.

Comment: The principle is correct, as the subtraction is used by x86 CMP instruction. Anyway, even the sign of the result is not enough. x86 uses zero, sign, and overflow flags for the [Jump if Less or Equal](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html). You need to emulate all these in your logic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've corrected the posting. It is safe to assume all integers will be 32 bits. We cannot use `< > - / * | &&` or any conditional statements, loops, no casting.

Comment: [`y=5` and `x=-6` seems to work fine.](https://ideone.com/7kOpKM)

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't work for `y=5` and `x=-6`?

Comment: @Brystephor yes, but C `int` math is not always safe, so that's *why* the assignment is misguided. For example `(y+~x+1)` can lead to signed overflow (if for example `y` is `INT_MIN` and `x` is `INT_MAX`). An optimizing compiler might then notice that some conditions are not *possible* if undefined behaviour happened - and therefore optimizes them out...

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work for `y=5` and `x=-6`? it sure seems like it does: https://ideone.com/7ZhVFV

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That is way above my level and I do not understand that.

Comment: @user3386109  You're correct. it does work. But there are some values it does not work for, I do not know which however.

we have a program that automatically tests the functions for multiple inputs, and if it gets everything 100% correct, it gives us the points. But if we get even one test wrong, it gives us a 0%. I've ran the exact code and am getting a 0%.

Comment: @Brystephor One possible problem is overflow. If `y` is a large positive number and `x` is a negative number, then it's possible that `y+~x+1` will overflow. Which is to say that the result may end up being negative when it should be positive. To demonstrate, try `y=2000000000` and `x=-1000000000`.

Comment: Yes, what @user3386109 said. To hold the difference between two 32-bit numbers requires 33 bits, whether they're signed or unsigned.

Comment: @user3386109 That is a problem. Any tips on what I can do to manage that? This entire assignment is killing me. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes this is an issue. I'm unsure of how to handle it or where to begin with it.

Comment: Can you assume 1. Two's-complement math, and 2. Sign-extending signed right shifts? Both are implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: other duplicates: [bitwise operators for finding less than in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14588160/995714), [Bitwise operations equivalent of greater than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10096599/995714), [Find if x is bigger than y using bitwise operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524038/995714), [Implement greater equal sign in C using only bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13396770/995714), [Greater than function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46390516/995714)

Comment: I added in the detailed de-obfuscation you asked for.

Comment: Two non-portable assumptions of your code are that signed right shifts are implementation-defined (unsigned right-shifts always zero-extend) and `int` is not necessarily 32 bits wide. The C standard also does not guarantee two’s-complement math, but all modern CPUs use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People here seem to be doing your homework for you, instead of analyzing the working example as you asked.

This is *not* how I would write the function at all, and in fact seems like obfuscated code. It’s your homework, so I won’t give a complete solution. (**ETA:** Well, you’ve already seen the answer.)

Let’s rewrite a bit as static single assignments with less-misleading names:

```
#include <limits.h> // For CHAR_BIT

int isLessOrEqual(const int x, const int y) {
   const int different_bits = x ^ y;      // sign = x ^ y;
   const int same_bits = ~different_bits; // isLess = ~sign;
   const int y_minus_x = y + (~x + 1);    // dif = y + (~x + 1);

   const int x_equals_y = !y_minus_x;           // equal = !dif; 
   const int bits_x_not_y = different_bits & x; // sign = sign & x;

   const int y_minus_x_inverted = ~y_minus_x;   // dif = ~dif;
   const int same_bits_not_in_y_minus_x =
     same_bits & y_minus_x_inverted             // isLess = isLess & dif;
   const int explained_below =
      same_bits_not_in_y_minus_x | bits_x_not_y; // isLess = isLess | sign;
   static const int sign_bit = 1 << (sizeof(y_minus_x)*CHAR_BIT - 1);
   const int truthy_iff_less =
     explained_below & sign_bit; // isLess = isLess & (1 << 31);

   const int is_less_or_equal =
     (!!truthy_iff_less) | x_equals_y; // isLessorEqual = (!!isLess) | (equal);

   return is_less_or_equal;  
}
```

I did make one fix: the posted code assumes that `int` is exactly 32 bits wide, which is not always true.  I compute the correct mask for the sign bit at compile time.

De-obfuscating this way, we see that we could have skipped the operations to turn `y_minus_x` into `explained_below`.  Looking more closely at `explained_below`, we see that each bit of it is set if any of the following is true: it is clear in all of x, y, and y-x, it is set in x and y but clear in y-x, or it is set in x but not y.  Since we only care about the sign bit, we get a truthy value when: x and y are both positive and y-x >= 0, x and y are both negative and y-x >= 0, or x < 0 and y > 0.

So this code is different from yours in that it checks for overflows, when y-x appears to be negative although x is negative and y positive, or underflows when y-x appears to be positive although x is positive and y negative.

There are much simpler solutions to this. If you’re assuming `x` and `y` are only 32 bits long anyway, just cast them to `long long int`.  It will take no longer on a 64-bit CPU and will never overflow or underflow. If you are working with your native word size, though, you could still shave off a few of those operations. You particularly don’t need to compute equality separately, and you could get by with fewer inversions.  Remember De Morgan’s laws!

#### Spoiler

Since everyone else posted the answers for you anyway, and you’ve already seen the algorithm, I guess I might as well post one too.  It’s similar except for coding style and some changes for portability (The type is not assumed to be exactly 32 bits wide, signed overflow is not assumed to behave like unsigned overflow, etc.), although it does still assume two’s-complement arithmetic.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int_fast32_t t;
typedef uint_fast32_t ut;

static const ut sign_bit = (ut)1 << (sizeof(ut)*CHAR_BIT - 1);
#define T_MIN INT_FAST32_MIN
#define T_MAX INT_FAST32_MAX

int lte( const t x, const t y )
{
  const ut y_minus_x = (ut)y + ~(ut)x + 1; // Assumes two’s-complement math.
  const ut different_bits = (ut)x ^ (ut)y;
  const ut x_not_y = (ut)x & ~(ut)y;
  const ut lte_without_overflow = ~(y_minus_x | different_bits);
  const ut truthy_result = (lte_without_overflow | x_not_y) & sign_bit;
  return !!truthy_result;
}

int print_testcase( const t x, const t y )
{
  static const char op_lte[] = "<=";
  static const char op_gt[] = ">";

  assert( lte(x, y) == (x <= y) );
  return printf( "%lld %s %lld.\n",
                 (long long int)x,
                 lte(x, y) ? op_lte : op_gt,
                 (long long int)y
               );
}

int main(void)
{
  static const t cases[][2] = {
    {1,1}, {-1,-1}, {2,1}, {1,2}, {-2,-1}, {-1, -2}, {2, -1}, {1, -2},
    {T_MAX, T_MIN}, {T_MIN, T_MAX}
  };
  static const ptrdiff_t ncases = sizeof(cases)/sizeof(cases[0]);

  for ( ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < ncases; ++i ) {
    print_testcase( cases[i][0], cases[i][1] );
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @hvd Thanks for pointing out a misleading sentence in my answer. Corrected.

Comment: This is what ive been looking for. I already submitted my assignment and such but i was looking to understand how these things work and why these things were beung done. If i wanted the answer, i couldve found it in a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

x-y can only overflow when x and y have opposite signs, so just handle those cases directly. Also no need to mask the sign bits with 1.

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
    int diff = (y+~x+1);
    int diffSign = diff>>31; 
    int xsign = x >> 31;
    int ysign = y >> 31;
    int forcetrue = xsign & ~ysign;
    int forcefalse = xsign | ~ysign;

    return !!(forcefalse&(forcetrue|~diffSign));
}
```

Of course this still has undefined behavior when the difference does overflow.

Comment: Yep. The overflow thing is killing all of these functions in these tests.

Comment: @user3386109: Yeah, was a bit tired last night. Need one more term, obviously. Also had the sense backwards. Fixed I think

Comment: @Nemo Yup, that works :)

Comment: nope, it can also overflow when x is negative and y is positive (on the negative side)

Comment: @LuisColorado: Yes, that is the same point user3386109 made in a comment (since deleted). In response, I fixed the code but not the accompanying text. Now I have fixed the text too

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found to work. This accounts for overflow as well. Needed a second way to check.

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
  int xSign, ySign, diffSign, answer;
  xSign = (x >> 31) & 1; //1 if x < 0
  ySign = (y>>31) & 1; //1 if y < 0
  diffSign = ((y+~x+1)>>31)&1; //1 if y-x < 0

  /*if xSign = 1, and y=0, then x must be less then y.
  if x&y are both positive, and the difference is negative, then
  y-x must be 0.*/
  answer = ((!ySign) & xSign) | ((!(xSign^ySign)) & !diffSign);
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: `(x >> 31) & 1` relies on implementation defined behavior. `(x & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000` would be better

Answer (score -2):

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
    int diff = x + ~y + 1; // diff = x-y
    int isNegative = (diff>>31) & 1; //if diff < 0, isNegative = 1
    int isZero = !(diff & (~1+1)); // if diff == 0, isZero = 1

    int xSign = (x>>31)&1;
    int ySign = (y>>31)&1;

    return isNegative | isZero | (xSign & (!ySign) & (!isNegative));
}
```

Comment: And what if diff == 2?

Comment: *int isZero = diff & ~1; // if diff == 0, isZero = 1* Huh? 0 bitwise anded with anything is 0, right?

Comment: Sorry. Mistake. Edited.

Comment: This does not pass all tests.

Comment: I edited the code. Works now?

Comment: Nope. This still does not work for all tests.

Comment: I missed a pair of parentheses. Edited. Now?

Comment: It does not handle overflow just like mine.

Comment: Handled overflow this time. Now?